# Total variation distance of $B(n,p)$ and $B(n+1,p)$

Tags: probability

How can one prove that $B(n,p)$ and $B(n+1,p)$ have distance $= \Omega (1/n)$?

My professor claimed that it does not need any tedious calculation. So I prefer to solve it without summation over the difference of Binomial coefficient. Can someone help me to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that someone has coupled $X \sim Bin(n,p)$ and $Y \sim Bin(n+1,p)$.

Calculate Expectations of $X,Y$ ,which are actually $np$ and $(n+1)p$ in this way:

$$\mathbb{E}X=\mathbb{E}[X|X=Y]\times \mathbb{P}[X=Y]+\mathbb{E}[X|X \ne Y]\times \mathbb{P}[X\ne Y]$$

$$\mathbb{E}Y=\mathbb{E}[Y|X=Y]\times \mathbb{P}[X=Y]+\mathbb{E}[Y|X \ne Y]\times \mathbb{P}[X\ne Y]$$

by setting $\mathbb{P}[X \ne Y]=q$ and subtracting these two equation we get:

$$p=q\times (\mathbb{E}[Y|X \ne Y]-\mathbb{E}[X|X \ne Y])$$

So

$$q=\frac{p}{\mathbb{E}[Y|X \ne Y]-\mathbb{E}[X|X \ne Y]}$$

Now to minimizing $q$ you need to maximize the denominator Which is at most $n+1$

Hence

$$q \ge \frac{p}{n+1}$$as you want.